# Facebook API crashed after changing hosting server

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, api, hosting

I implemented the Facebook API on my website and everything was working fine.
Two days ago I moved my website to another server and the Facebook API stopped working.
I reset my APP Secret Key thinking that it may fix the problem but it didn't.

The javascript works fine. I can connect using it but when I try to get the user with php it says some error like this: **Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating application.**

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! you need to make sure that the values for the appID and secret are strings and not numbers. Silly but I guess that depending on the configuration of PHP sometimes the appID will work as an int and sometimes must be a string. So add quotes to it :)

```
'appId'  => '216500000000000',
'secret' => '*************************',
```

Comment: Where did you obtain this info? The OP didn't mention anything of the sort.

Comment: We were both working on it together and found the problem. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the new host has the same or newer version of PHP running as the old host. Make sure they have cURL installed and activated. Make sure they have not disabled any remote connection functions such as `file_get_contents()` or anything that you might be using on the PHP side which would connect to the Facebook API.

Comment: Thank you, I already checked and everything is the same or better. The only differences I found are the following parameters: <br/>
odbc.allow_persistent  <br/>
odbc.check_persistent   <br/><br/>
In the new server they are set to off. In the old one they are on. Can this be related to the issue?

Is there anything else that I can check?